Why im having this error? "Bleak develop branch"
I have solved this issue in the past but I don't recall how.
When compiling with Buildozer I get this error:
[DEBUG]:      setuptools.extern.packaging.version.InvalidVersion: Invalid version: 'bleak develop branch' 
I install bleak like this:
pip install https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/archive/refs/heads/develop.zip

And also try with the stable version just in case.
The app im trying is just an example from the repository
https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/tree/develop/examples/kivy
and this is the buildozer.spec (is just the same as the repository)
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = BD

# (str) Package name
package.name = bleaki

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.github.hbldh


# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1.0

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements =
    python3,
    kivy,
    bleak,
    async_to_sync,
    async-timeout,
    typing_extensions


# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY


# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0


# (list) Permissions
android.permissions =
    BLUETOOTH,
    BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
    BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
    BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION


# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
android.accept_sdk_license = True


# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.archs = arm64-v8a

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

p4a.branch = develop

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes = recipes
p4a.local_recipes = ../../bleak/backends/p4android/recipes


# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

What am doing wrong?
Thanks
